# How would I make my buttons scrollable?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have 3 buttons that I would like to make possible for it to scroll.

I've tried adding `<ScrollView`'s to encapsulate each `<LinearLayout` that contains `<Button`'s but that didn't work and just gave me more problems.

How can I use `<ScrollView` the correct way so that my buttons scroll?

[image]

Here's `activity-maps.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.mancj.example.MapsActivity">
    </fragment>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:hint="Search"
            android:id="@+id/searchBar"
            android:layout_width="289dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="onSearch"
            android:text="SEARCH" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="something1"
        android:id="@+id/button2"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
            android:text="something2"
            android:id="@+id/button3"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="440dp"
            android:text="something3"
            android:id="@+id/button4"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Which direction do you wanna scroll them?

Comment: better design would be not making them scroll. as a user, how would i know if they scroll or not? maybe a custom dialog would be better?

Comment: Encapsulate the Scroll View in a LinearView and give it a fixed height in dp that is smaller than the height of those 3 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="co.sovf.example.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A scrollview will just ensure that all buttons can be seen by scrolling if the buttons take up more space than the screen, which they do not; see:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Perhaps you mean a bottom sheet, as seen in a similar way to what you have in google maps? A description of how to use and implement can be found at:

https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066